# How to make checkstyle checking dependent on skipTests?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I'm trying to skip checkstyle check while I'm running `mvn clean install -DskipTests` , but the checkstyle check should run during `mvn test`. I was able to achive this with `-Dcheckstyle.skip` argument but I don't want that. If the tests are skipped skip the checkstyle as well. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, you can skip checking by adding arguments to the command line. For skipping checking styles (e.g., checking code format, code quality, unit test coverage, etc.), you can use the following command:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip = true
```

If you want to skip checking code quality, you can use the following command:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip = true -Dcheckstyle.skip = true
```

Here, checkstyle.skip is a property that the Maven Check Styles plugin checks to see if the code meets the defined coding standards. By setting this property to true, you can tell Maven to skip the Check Styles phase during the build process.

Comment: yeah I'm able to do that via arguments, My idea was to just use -DskipTests in such a way that ,if the tests are skipped skip the checkstyle check as well